# Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring (with unity), and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $R/I \cong R$. Then is $I=(0)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian, ring-homomorphism

> Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring (with unity), and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $R/I \cong R$. Then is it true that $I=(0)$ ?

I know that a surjective ring endomorphism of a Noetherian ring is also injective, and since there is a natural surjection from $R$ onto $R/I$ we get a surjection from $R$ onto $R$, but the problem is I can not determine the map explicitly and I am not sure about the statement. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need an explicit map for the argument. If it is true "that surjective ring endomorphism on Noetherian ring is injective" the claim follows as you said. (I phrase it like this as I was not aware of  that result, but this  might well be just ignorance of my part.)

Comment: @quid : the result I stated is true ... but how do you derive the required claim from that result ?

Comment: Well, let $f: R/I \to R$ be an isomorphism, and $\pi : R \to R/I$ the projection. Then $f \circ \pi$ is a surjective endomorphism of $R$, hence it is injective. In particular $I = \ker \pi \subseteq \ker (f \circ \pi) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $R/I$ and $R$ are isomorphic. Let us denote the isomophism by $f:R/I \to R$.

Let $\pi:R \to R/I$ denote the usual map $x \mapsto x + I$. 
This is a of course a surjective ring homomorphism.

The composition $f \circ \pi : R \to R$ is thus a surjective ring endomorphism (the composition of surjections is a surjection).

By the result quoted in the question $f \circ \pi$ is an isomorphism, in particular it is injective. It follows that $\pi$ is injective, otherwise the composition could not be injective.

The kernel of $\pi$ is thus $\{0\}$; it is also  is $I$. Thus $I = \{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f:R/I\to R$ is an isomorphism and $I \ne (0)$. Let $\overline{J} = f^{-1}I\subset R/I$ and $J\subset R$ be the preimage of $\overline J$ in $R$. Now $I \ne (0)$ implies $J$ strictly contains $I$; but $R/J \cong (R/I)/\overline J$ which is isomorphic to $R/I$ via $f$, and so isomorphic to $R$ by hypothesis. Now you can repeat for $J$; you will find a never-ending sequence of ever-larger ideals, contradicting the Noetherian property.

Note that the problem statement is somewhat ambiguous; you could interpret the isomorphism to be "isomorphic as $R$-modules" (in which case the problem would be trivial).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a$ is a proper ideal. Suppose they were isomorphic. Then $\varphi: A \to A/a$ is some arbitrary isomorphism, and correspondingly $\varphi(a) := I_{1} \subset A/a$ is an ideal (proper inclusion as $a \subset A$ is a proper inclusion). By the correspondence principle, $I_{1} \subset A/a$ pulls back to an ideal $a \subset I'_{1} \subset A$ which are all proper inclusions (as $\varphi(a)$ is nonzero in $A/a$), where $I'_{1} = \pi^{-1}(I_{1})$ for $\pi: A \to A/a$ the canonical projection map.

The key step is that $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism $\overline{\varphi}: A/a \to A/I_{1}$. But then $\overline{\varphi}(I_{1}):= I_{2}$ pulls back to an ideal $I'_{2} \subset A$ (proper inclusion using the same rationale as above) via $\pi_{1}: A \to A/I_{1}$ the canonical projection, such that $a \subset I'_{1} \subset I'_{2}$ in $A$ are all proper inclusions. Now iterate this process to yield an ascending chain which does not stabilize. Contradiction!

Comment: By $\varphi$ you don’t mean the canonical projection, do you? Because for every commutative ring and nonzero ideal the projection will never be injective, so in particular not an isomorphism. There may however be a noncanonical isomorphism $A\cong A/\mathfrak{a}$...

Comment: No $\varphi$ is just some isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A\approx A/a$. Of those $A$ ideals $a'$ satisfying $A\approx A/a'$ choose $b$ maximal with respect to set inclusion. Consequently we may choose a non-trivial proper ideal $C$ of the the quotient ring $A/b$ such that $A\approx (A/b)/C$ but then $$A\approx (A/b)/C\approx A/(b+c)$$ where $c:=\{x\in A:x+b\in C\}$ is the pullback $A$ ideal of $C$, which then violates the maximality of $b$ because $C$ is non-trivial and thus $b+c$ would properly contain $b$.