# If $A/I \cong A/J$ as rings and $I\subseteq J,$ then $I=J.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

Let $A$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of $A.$

Suppose that $I\subseteq J$ and that $A/I \cong A/J$ as rings.

I want to prove that $I=J.$

---

Observations so far:

1) If we drop the hypothesis $I\subseteq J,$ then the result is false:

$$\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X)\cong \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(Y) \text{ but } (X)\neq (Y).$$

2) If $A/I\cong A/J$ as $A$-modules, then $I=J$:

$$I=\mathrm{Ann}_A(A/I)=\mathrm{Ann}_A(A/J)=J.$$

I'm now a bit stuck as to how to proceed. Any hints would be most helpful!

Many thanks :)

Comment: It should also be noted that Noetherian is required.  Consider $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ with $I=0,J=(x_1)$.

Comment: Yes indeed - thank you :)

Comment: I think it is essentially a duplicate of the question linked (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905186/let-r-be-a-commutative-noetherian-ring-with-unity-and-let-i-be-an-ideal-o), despite the reopen votes.

Comment: Well, to see this you have to replace (in the linked question) $R$ by $A/I$ and $I$ be $J/I$, and this could be hard to perceive ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that $I\subsetneq J$.  By induction, we can construct an infinite ascending chain of ideals as follows:

- Put $J_0=I$ and $J_1=J$.  Then $J_0\subsetneq J_1$ and $A/J_0 \cong A/J_1$.
- Assume that for a certain integer $n$, we have ideals $J_n$ and $J_{n+1}$ such that $J_n\subsetneq J_{n+1}$ and $A/J_n \cong A/J_{n+1}$.  Via this isomorphism, the non-trivial ideal $J_{n+1}/J_n$ of the left-hand side corresponds to a non-trivial ideal of the right-hand side.  This ideal has the form $J_{n+2}/J_{n+1}$, where $J_{n+2}$ is an ideal of $A$ with $J_{n+1}\subsetneq J_{n+2}$.  Moreover, 
  $$ A/J_{n+2} \cong (A/J_{n+1})/(J_{n+2}/J_{n+1}) \cong (A/J_{n})/(J_{n+1}/J_n)\cong A/J_{n+1}. $$

By induction, we have constructed an infinite sequence of ideals
$$J_0\subsetneq J_1\subsetneq J_2\subsetneq \ldots, $$

so $A$ is not Noetherian, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah yes. Very nice! Thank you very much :)