# If $K[X]/I \cong K[X]/J$ with $I \subset J$ then $I=J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $K$ be a field and $I,J$ are ideals of $K[X].$ Then if $K[X]/I \cong K[X]/J$     with $I \subset J$ then can one say that $I=J$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $R$ be any Noetherian ring and let $I\subseteq J\subseteq R$ be ideals such that $R/I$ and $R/J$ are isomorphic as rings.  Then $I=J$.

To prove this, we may first replace $R$ by $R/I$, and so we may assume $I=0$.  We then have a ring-isomorphism $R/J\to R$ for some ideal $J$ and want to show $J=0$.  Equivalently, we have a surjective ring-homomorphism $f:R\to R$ with kernel $J$, and want to show $J=0$.

So we are reduced to showing that if $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $f:R\to R$ is a surjective ring-homomorphism, then $f$ is injective.  To prove this, note that if $\ker f\neq 0$, then the inclusions $$0\subset\ker f\subset \ker f^2\subset\ker f^3\subset\dots$$ are all strict.  Indeed, each of these inclusions is obtained by applying $f^{-1}$ to the previous inclusion, and $f^{-1}$ preserves strict inclusions since $f$ is surjective.  So this is an infinite ascending chain of ideals in $R$, which contradicts the assumption that $R$ is Noetherian.

---

Alternatively, in the case $R=K[X]$, you can give a proof in the spirit of the other answers which used $K$-dimension (assuming the isomorphism was an isomorphism of $K$-algebras) which works assuming just a ring-isomorphism.  The trick is to use length of modules as a substitute for $K$-dimension.

First, note that the ring $K[X]/I$ is artinian iff $I\neq 0$, so if $K[X]/I\cong K[X]/J$ then $I=0$ iff $J=0$.  So let us assume $I,J\neq 0$.

In this case, $K[X]/J$ is a quotient of $K[X]/I$, and both are artinian rings.  Note that the length of $K[X]/J$ as a module over itself is the same as its length as a $K[X]/I$-module, since $K[X]/I$-submodules of $K[X]/J$ are the same as $K[X]/J$-submodules.  If $J\neq I$ so $K[X]/J$ is a proper quotient of $K[X]/I$, then $K[X]/J$ has smaller length than $K[X]/I$ as a $K[X]/I$-module, and hence the length of $K[X]/J$ as a module over itself is less than the length of $K[X]/I$ as a module over itself.  Thus the rings $K[X]/I$ and $K[X]/J$ cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Great proof. I also knew the property of noetherian rings, but I hadn't the clear thought to bring this in combination with the given problem.

Comment: The deeper result about noetherian rings is also found in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905186/let-r-be-a-commutative-noetherian-ring-with-unity-and-let-i-be-an-ideal-o

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

First, note that $K[X]/I$ has infinite $K$-dimension if and only if $I=(0)$.  So the result is true if either of $I$ or $J$ is $(0)$.

Assume now that $I$ and $J$ are both non-zero.  Recall that $K[X]$ is a principal ideal domain.  Hence there are polynomials $P$ and $Q$ such that $I=(P)$ and $J=(Q)$.  Then the $K$-dimension of $K[X]/I$ (or $K[X]/J$) is the degree of $P$ (or $Q$, respectively).  Thus $P$ and $Q$ have the same degree.  Finally, $I\subset J$ implies that $P$ is divisible by $Q$.  Thus $P$ and $Q$ are equal up to a non-zero scalar factor, and so $I=J$.

Comment: Nice solution @Pierre-Guy Plamondon

Comment: Only one question.. can it be extended to $K[X,Y]$ ??

Comment: Note that this answer assumes $\cong$ means "isomorphic as $K$-algebras", rather than just as rings.

Comment: @EricWofsey  Yes, this is an important assumption, which I thought the OP meant (even though it was unsaid).  I would suggest that either the OP explicitly adds this assumption in their question, or explicitly states that this is not the assumption (and then this answer is not valid anymore).

Comment: Can there be any ring isomorphism which is not $K-$algebra isomorphism in this problem @ Eric Wofsey

Comment: You can have a ring isomorphism which is not a $K$-algebra isomorphism.  However, the answer to the original question is still yes for ring isomorphisms--you can just use length as a replacement for $K$-dimension.  See my answer.

Comment: Can you give an explicit example of a ring isomorphism between two K-algebra  which is not K-algebra isomorphism @Eric Wofsey

Comment: @user371231  Any field automorphism of $K$ that is not the identity is a ring isomorphism that is not a $K$-algebra isomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** As Eric Wofsey mentioned, this proof only works if $\cong$ means "isomorphic as $K$-Algebras".

If $I\subset J$ we have 
$$(K[X]/I)/(J/I)\cong K[X]/J$$
So we get in the given situation

$$(K[X]/I)/(J/I)\cong K[X]/I$$

Since $K[X]/I$ is a finite dimensional vector space, this is only possible for $J/I=\{0\}$ i.e. $I=J$.

Comment: It is impossible for maximal ideals to $I \subset J$.

Comment: This is also a good solution

Comment: The first proof wasn't correct, this is a correction.