# On ring isomorphism between cartesian products of rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, direct-product, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

> Let $R$ be a (non-zero) commutative ring with unity. For $n \in \mathbb N$ denote by $R^n$ the ring under usual co-ordinate wise addition and multiplication. If $R$ is moreover artinian and $R^m \cong R^n$ as rings, then is it true that $m=n $ ?

I know that the similar claim is true if we look at $R^n$ as $R$-module. For my question of the ring case  it is easy to see that $R^m \cong R^n$ as rings implies $m=n$ is true if $R$ has finitely many idempotents or say if $R$ has finitely many maximal ideals  and  is false if $R=\prod_{  \mathbb N}S=S^\mathbb N$ for any ring $S$.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose $m<n$. Then the composition $R^m\simeq R^n\stackrel{\pi}\to R^m$ (here $\pi$ is the projection on the first $m$ components) is a surjective ring homomorphism, and let $I$ be its kernel. We have $R^m/I\simeq R^m$ and since $R^m$ is noetherian we get $I=(0)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905186/let-r-be-a-commutative-noetherian-ring-with-unity-and-let-i-be-an-ideal-o)), a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following , all rings are commutative with unity which is non-zero.

The claim is true in general for  Noetherian rings ( hence also for  Artinian rings  as  Artinian rings are Noetherian )

First let us recall a fact : If $R$ is  Noetherian ring then any surjective ring  endomorphism of $R$ is isomorphism . This is a very well known fact and a proof follows by considering the ascending chain of ideals $\{\ker f^n \}_{n\ge 1}$ if $f:R \to R$ is the given surjective  ring homomorphism .

Now since ideals of a direct product of rings $R \times S$ looks like $I \times J$ where $I,J$ are ideals of $R , S$ respectively , so if $R,S$ are Noetehrian rings , then  $R \times S$ also is a Noetherian ring. Now suppose $R$ is a Noetherian ring and let , if possible ,  $R^m \cong R^n$ as rings , for some integers $m>n\ge 1$ . Now consider the surjective ring homomprhism  $f: R^m \to R^n$ defined as $f(r_1,...,r_m)=(r_1,...,r_n) , \forall (r_1,...,r_m) \in R^m$ ( this is surjective as $m >n$ ) . Now let $g : R^n \to R^m$ be a given isomorphism . Then $g \circ f : R^m \to R^m$ is a surjective ring homomorphism , and then since $R^m$ is  Noetherian ring , we get that $g\circ f$ is an isomorphism . Hence $f$ is an injective , so $\ker f =\{0\}$ . But now by definition of $f$ , $\ker f =\{(0,...,r_{n+1},...,r_m)\in R^m | r_{n+1},...,r_m \in R\} \cong R^{m-n}$ as $R$-modules , so $R^{m-n} \cong 0$ as $R$-modules ; but as $m-n \ge 1$ and $R$ has unity which is non-zero , so $R^{m-n}$ cannot be singleton , contradiction ! Thus if $R$ is Noetherian and $R^m \cong R^n$ as rings then $m=n$

Comment: @users : Wow! That's awesome and easy too . Thanks . Your $\ker f :=\{(0,...,r_{n+1} , ..., r_m) \in R^m : r_{n+1},...,r_m \in R\}$ ; is right ? definitely it can not be $\{0\}$ if $m>n$ without even having to identify with $R^{m-n}$ ; but yours is okay too. Thanks again

Comment: @misao : You are welcome . And yes, that is exactly my kernel of $f$ . I have now added that explicit expression in my answer

Comment: @users yes, I think this approach works. The same argument will work for rings with the ACC on ideals, a much larger class containing right noetherian rings. (There is no need to stick to commutative rings, it was never important at any point.

Comment: @rschwieb : yes true , commutativity was not needed ;  its actually a bit bad habit of mine to assume commutative beforehand . Thank you for your attention

Comment: @rschwieb : what do you think about the claim when $R$ is an arbitrary $k$-algebra where $k$ is a field ? Can we then conclude $m=n$ ? (the isomorphism is still only assumed to be ring isomorphism) . We only need to look at infinitely generated algebras due to this answer

Comment: @misao The very first counterexample in the very first comment on your question is an $\mathbb R$ algebra for which $R\cong R^n$ as rings for any $n$. So obviously not.

Comment: @rschwieb : Ah true , I was being stupid

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $A$ is a commutative artinian ring, then $A/J(A)$ is a *finite* product of fields, where $J(A)$ denotes the Jacobson radical; if a ring is a product of fields, the number of factors is uniquely determined.

The result is generally not true if the ring is not artinian: take an infinite product of copies of a field, which is isomorphic to its square.

Comment: How do I get to $R/J(R)$ from $R$ ? The statement is certainly true for semisimple artinian rings as you suggest, I can see that .. but I don't really get how to work with $R/J(R) $ ...

Comment: @misao The Jacobson radical is obviously invariant under ring isomorphisms. So, under your assumptions, $R^n/J(R^n)\cong R^m/J(R^m)$; on the other hand, $R^n/J(R^n)\cong(R/J(R))^n$.

Comment: ah I see  ... since the Jacobson radical gets send to Jacobson radical ... thanks . Do you know what happens if $R$ is Noetherian ?

Comment: @misao I feel there are counterexample, but have none at hand.

Comment: I could be misremembering, but I think there is probably a result for semiperfect rings about the uniqueness of the number of idempotents in a decomposition of $1$ into a complete orthogonal set, and that would probably extend the argument given for Artinian rings.  Noetherian rings are surprising enough that they might furnish a counterexample (but none occurred to me either.)

Comment: @rschwieb It's probably true for semiperfect rings, I concur.

Comment: @egreg : do you think the claim holds when $R$ is a finitely generated algebra over some field ? Btw. ; for the artinian case , we might see it much simpler way by noting that commutative artinian ring has finitely many maximal ideals , and it is easy to observe (as I also commented in my question ) that the claim holds for rings with finitely many maximal ideals ...

Comment: @misao Yes, finitely many maximal ideals suffice. As for fg algebras, I don't know.

Comment: @rschwieb : it holds for commutative  Noetherian ring with unity , where the unity is non-zero . Please see my answer

Comment: @egreg : I have posted an answer . Could you please verify ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses some topology .

All rings are commutative with unity in the following .

We will show that the result is true for any ring $R$ satisfying ACC on radical ideals .

Let $R$ be a ring satisfying ACC on radical ideals and such that $R^m \cong R^n$ as rings .  Then $Spec(R^m)$ and $Spec(R^n)$ are homeomorphic topological spaces ( see Atiyah ; Macdonald's , Commutative Algebra book for this) . Now as $R$ satisfies ACC on radical ideals , so $Spec(R)$ is  a Noetherian topological space ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_topological_space , also Atiyah ; Macdonald's book) ; hence $Spec(R)$ has finitely many connected components (see http://www-personal.umich.edu/~gcheong/schemes/Notherian-fin-conn-components.pdf for example) . Let $Spec(R)$ have $t$ ( $>0$) many connected components . Now since the spectrum of a finite direct product of rings is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of the individual spectra   , $Spec (R^n)$ has $tn$ many connected components. And since homeomorphism between topological spaces preserves the no. of connected components , so $tm=tn$  ,and hence $m=n$